# How to check if a list of <T> has order (asc or desc) or not, according its properties?

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

To get the order (if any) I'm doing this:

(`<T>` always has at least one property)

```
private bool GetOrder<T>(IQueryable<T> list, out string order) where T: class, new()
{
    var props = (new T().GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray());

    foreach (var pro in props)
    {
        // order ascending by each property
        var comparable = list.OrderBy(x => pro.GetValue(x, null)).AsQueryable();

        if (list.SequenceEqual(comparable))
        {
            order = pro.Name + " asc";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // then descending
            comparable = list.OrderByDescending(x => pro.GetValue(x, null)).AsQueryable();

            if (list.SequenceEqual(comparable))
            {
                order = pro.Name + " desc";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    order = "none";
    return false;
}
```

Testing this I'm getting acceptable results, may be slow (4-5 secs for 500K elements) but some way works.

Some issues come when order criteria may be more than one, and this method only get the first, is there any other (faster) way, I'm pretty sure there is, but I can find it or get it.

Comment: You don't need an ordered collection to compare elements against to know if a collection is sorted. A collection is sorted if for every nth element the (n+1)th element is greater/lesser than the nth element, depending on if you're sorting ascending or descending. If you find any case where that condition isn't true, the collection is not sorted. If you reach the end of the collection, the list is sorted.

Comment: What is the order for an empty list? For a list with a single element?

Answer (score 0):

A more performant approach would enumerate through the list; if an element appears out of order, it is unsorted, and otherwise it is sorted.

Here is one (basic) implementation using an extension method:

```
// define possible orderings
public enum SortOrder
{
    Ascending,
    Descending,
    Constant,
    Unordered,
    Empty
}

public static class Extensions
{
    // simple method to get the ordering of an enumeration
    public static SortOrder GetOrdering<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
        IComparer<T> comparer = null) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (!list.Any())
            return SortOrder.Empty;
        if (comparer == null)
            comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        SortOrder ret = SortOrder.Constant;
        T last = list.First();
        // for each element after the first, compare with previous value
        foreach (T v in list.Skip(1))
        {
            var c = comparer.Compare(last, v);
            last = v;
            if (c == 0) continue;

            if ((c < 0 && ret == SortOrder.Ascending)
                || c > 0 && ret == SortOrder.Descending)
                return SortOrder.Unordered;
            else if (ret == SortOrder.Constant)
                ret = c < 0 ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

At this point, the extension method can be used like so:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "Z", "z", "z" };
List<int> l3 = new List<int> { 8, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> l4 = new List<int> { 8, 4, 4, 3, 2 };
Console.WriteLine(l1.GetOrdering()); // returns Ascending
Console.WriteLine(l2.GetOrdering())); // return Ascending
Console.WriteLine(l2.GetOrdering(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))); // returns Constant
Console.WriteLine(l3.GetOrdering())); // return Unordered
Console.WriteLine(l4.GetOrdering())); // return Descending
```

Note that since the extension method enumerates through the list, rather than sorts it, performance in the worst case is O(N) for an ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the new constraint as you can just use typeof(T) instead of creating the class then doing GetType.  This should be faster since the code just compares it loops over the data once.

This method will return back all the properties that it could be ordered by, not just the first (I assumed you wanted that changed based on your comment to your question).

Like yours if the list is empty it just returns back "none".  If they are all equal it will return back the default of "asc".  Unlike yours this code doesn't order the property by their name since it will return back all that are sorted.

Also you should be careful with IQueryable as that could be a database call and if you loop over it many times you could be hitting a database multiple times. I switched it to IEnumerable but if you need IQueryable you could switch it back.

```
private string GetOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    where T : class
{
    // Comparer class to see greater or less than or equal
    var comparer = Comparer.Default;

    // Track currrent orderby so far
    var propsOrderBy = typeof (T).GetProperties()
                                 .Where(p => p.CanRead)
                                 .ToDictionary(p => p, _ => 0);

    // List of all the property since we can update dictionary if we iterate over it
    var props = new List<PropertyInfo>(propsOrderBy.Keys);
    // Last value
    var previousValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // Need to iterate over list to compare data
    foreach (var data in list)
    {
        // Check each property if we haven't removed it yet
        foreach (var prop in props.Where(propsOrderBy.ContainsKey))
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(data);
            if (previousValues.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
            {
                var comparison = comparer.Compare(value, previousValues[prop.Name]);
                // If comparison didn't say it was equal and it's not the same as the previous order by
                if (comparison != 0 && (comparison != propsOrderBy[prop]))
                {
                    // If zero first time setting it
                    if (propsOrderBy[prop] == 0)
                    {
                        propsOrderBy[prop] = comparison;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not our order key so remove it
                        propsOrderBy.Remove(prop);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Store last value
            previousValues[prop.Name] = value;
        }

        // No point to keep looping if we know all fields have no order
        if (!propsOrderBy.Any())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (previousValues.Any() && propsOrderBy.Any())
    {
        return String.Join(", ", propsOrderBy.Select(p => p.Key.Name + (p.Value < 0 ? " desc" : " asc ")));
    }
    else
    {
        return "none";
    }
}
```